# PowerShell: Dot in Enum Name Causing Add-Type to Fail

Tags: c#, powershell, enums, add-type

I have created enums below in PowerShell. However, if I have a dot in the enum name (for example, "Name.A") then Add-Type would return an error. How do I go about it? I don't want to remove the dot from "Name.A".

```
$TypeEnum = "
    namespace Types {
        public enum Id { 
            Name.A = 1,
            NameB = 2,
            NameC = 3
        }   
    }"

Add-Type -TypeDefinition $TypeEnum -Language CSharpVersion3

([Types.Id]::'Name.A').value__
```

Here is the error that I get:

> Add-Type : c:\Users\User1\AppData\Local\Temp\ab0z5i1y.0.cs(4) : }
>   expected c:\Users\User1\AppData\Local\Temp\ab0z5i1y.0.cs(3) :
>   public enum Id {  c:\Users\User1\AppData\Local\Temp\ab0z5i1y.0.cs(4)
>   : >>>             Name.A = 1,
>   c:\Users\User1\AppData\Local\Temp\ab0z5i1y.0.cs(5) :
>   NameB = 2, At line:10 char:1
>   + Add-Type -TypeDefinition $TypeEnum -Language CSharpVersion3
>   + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (c:\Users\User1...513: } expected:CompilerError) [Add-Type], Exception
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : SOURCE_CODE_ERROR,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.AddTypeCommand
>   Add-Type : c:\Users\User1\AppData\Local\Temp\ab0z5i1y.0.cs(8) : Type
>   or namespace definition, or end-of-file expected
>   c:\Users\User1\AppData\Local\Temp\ab0z5i1y.0.cs(7) :         }
>   c:\Users\User1\AppData\Local\Temp\ab0z5i1y.0.cs(8) : >>>     } At
>   line:10 char:1
>   + Add-Type -TypeDefinition $TypeEnum -Language CSharpVersion3
>   + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (c:\Users\User1...f-file expected:CompilerError) [Add-Type], Exception
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : SOURCE_CODE_ERROR,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.AddTypeCommand
>   Add-Type : Cannot add type. There were compilation errors. At line:10
>   char:1
>   + Add-Type -TypeDefinition $TypeEnum -Language CSharpVersion3
>   + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [Add-Type], InvalidOperationException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : COMPILER_ERRORS,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.AddTypeCommand   Unable
>   to find type [Types.Id]: make sure that the assembly containing this
>   type is loaded. At line:12 char:1
>   + ([Types.Id]::'Name.A').value__
>   + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (Types.Id:TypeName) [], RuntimeException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : TypeNotFound

Comment: Thats not valid C#.

Comment: Can you please elaborate as in what needs to change, etc.?

Comment: C# do not allow dot to be part of identifier.

Comment: Change `Name.A` to `NameA`.  Periods are not allowed in identifiers in C#.  Why do you not want to remove the dot?

Comment: Because the Id is fetched in to me, but I just thought of something which is to remove the dot from the name before getting the enum value.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a limitation of .Net, and by extension PowerShell and C#. Enum member names can't have punctuation in them.

Thus the short answer is, you can't make this work without doing something hacky (You'd have to change name.A to name[CharacterCode]A or add a description, or some other weird thing you really shouldn't do)